# Hiding Bitmap Layers on Pebble Watchface

Tags: pebble-sdk, cloudpebble

I've been building a pretty basic watch face that includes mute & bluetooth indicator icons. I've been trying to use `layer_set_hidden()` to hide the layers depending on the connection and mute state but I've run in to some trouble. The `layer_set_hidden()` command works in the `init()` function but not in `main_window_load()`. It causes the app to crash on load and nothing is visible. The logs are showing:

```
[ERROR] ault_handling.c:97: App fault! {77b4b888-5c9a-40b4-9dca-54f0eb498831} PC: 0x80a5204 LR: 0x441
```

I've been developing on CloudPebble and the Github is [here](https://github.com/gwoods22/WatchFace/blob/master/src/c/main.c). I've put in some obnoxious comments showing the 2 lines that are causing the crash as well as the `layer_set_hidden()` call in `init()` that works fine.

One other less critical issue is setting the background colour of a transparent png on a bitmap layer is not changing. I the default is black but I want my black icons to show up on a white background. Those outlines have also been outlined with big comments.

Any help would be appreciated!